# Record Screen Function TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy, image-processing, python-tesseract

I want to have a function that outputs the image so I can compare it with the other images, it is also supposed to output the text which is in the picture

But i get this Error `TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'`

Here is my Code

```
def rec_screen(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    printscreen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2)))
    printscreen = cv2.cvtColor(printscreen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cv2.imshow('window', printscreen)
    if (cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
        print("1")
return ([printscreen,(tess.image_to_string(printscreen))])

def crawler():
    print(rec_screen(889, 259, 917, 247)[1])
```

I've tried this didnt work

```
gray = (np.float32(imgUMat), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is 28x0 and that's why you get an error on `cv2.imshow('window', printscreen)`

This is because you are passing the coordinates wrong, try:

```
def crawler():
    print(rec_screen(889, 247, 917, 259)[1])
```

(`y2` should be bigger than `y1`)